# How to loop fetch data and store it into state array in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, arrays, fetch

I am trying to loop a fetch request based on a array with forEach. How do I store the data in a single array to later render it in JSX?

This is my beginner's code so far.

```
import "./App.css";

function Temp2() {
  var payloadArray = [9837, 5021, 0162, 7553];
  let final = [];

  let fetchNewArray = function () {
    payloadArray.forEach((payload) => {
      final.push(
        fetch("API URL", {
          payload,
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            let q = json.data.toString(); // q = '1324646'
            return q;
          })
      );
    });

    return Promise.all(final);
  };
  console.log(final); // was expecting final = ["q value 1", "q value 2" ,"q value 3"]
  return (
    <div>
      <header className="App-header">
        <button onClick={fetchNewArray}>GET VALUES</button>
        {final.map((e, i) => {
          return <p key={i}>{e}</p>;
        })}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Temp2;
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `fetchNewArray` using a `useEffect` when the component load and set the values from `Promise.all` in a state variable:

```
function Temp2() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  var payloadArray = [9837, 5021, 0162, 7553];

  let fetchNewArray = function () {
    const promises = [];
    payloadArray.forEach((payload) => {
      promises.push(
        fetch('API URL', {
          payload,
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            let q = json.data.toString(); // q = '1324646'
            return q;
          })
      );
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((v) => setValues(v));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <button onClick={fetchNewArray}>GET VALUES</button>
        {values.length ? (
          values.map((e, i) => {
            return <p key={i}>{e}</p>;
          })
        ) : (
          <>Loading...</>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Temp2;
```

Comment: Why did you add the `useEffect`? It seems he wants to fetch the data only on click on the button. That's what I understood.

Comment: Thanks lpizzinidev. your solution worked for me. I removed the useEffect as I wanted it to only show on click as OneO said. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @OneQ Missed that. Thank you for pointing that out.